# Why will this json data not load?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Trying to import dictionaries from an external Json file using json.loads, however when I do this I am met with an error message.

```
import json
import random

winner = "None"
winners = 0

class player:
    def __init__(self, playernum):
        self.playernum = playernum
        self.score = random.randint(1,6)
        self.name = "foo"
player1 = player(1)
player2 = player(2)

if player1.score > player2.score:
    winner = player1.name
    winners = player1.score
elif player2.score > player1.score:
    winner = player2.name
    winners = player2.score

with open("highscores.txt", "a") as f:
  json.dump({winner : winners}, f)
f.close()

with open("highscores.txt", "r") as f:
  scores = json.load(f)
f.close()

print(scores)
```

Highscores.txt currently contains 7 dictionaries; {"Daniel": 71}{"Jonathan": 26}{"Jonathan": 58}{"Daniel": 90}{"Jonathan": 57}{"Jonathan": 80}{"Jonathan": 50}

Shouldn't it print out the file, which should be comprised of winner:winners dictionaries?
Instead, I get this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/jonat/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36-32/neacode.py", line 119, in <module>
    scores = json.load(f)

  File "C:\Users\jonat\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\json\__init__.py", line 299, in load
    parse_constant=parse_constant, object_pairs_hook=object_pairs_hook, **kw)
  File "C:\Users\jonat\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\json\__init__.py", line 354, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Users\jonat\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\json\decoder.py", line 342, in decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Extra data", s, end)
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 1 column 15 (char 14)
```

Why?

Comment: {"Daniel": 71}{"Jonathan": 26}{"Jonathan": 58}{"Daniel": 90}{"Jonathan": 57}{"Jonathan": 80}{"Jonathan": 50} is what highscores.txt looks like at the moment

Comment: Please put that in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you are appending dictionaries to a file, which is not valid json syntax:

```py
from io import StringIO
import json

s = '''{"a": 1}
{"b": 2}
{"c": 3}'''

fh = StringIO(s)
json.load(fh) # JSONDecodeError
```

Furthermore, using `json.dump` in a file opened in append (`'a'`) mode won't include newlines, which yields even worse non-json. To handle this, I'd change how you append to the file:

```py
with open('highscores.txt', 'a') as fh:
    obj = json.dumps({winner: winners})+'\n' # note the added newline here
    fh.write(obj)
```

This will allow you to read in the file line by line:

```py
with open('highscores.txt', 'r') as fh:
    scores = [json.loads(line.strip()) for line in fh]

print(scores)
```

Also, note that you don't have to call `fh.close()` as the `with` statement will take care of that for you

Comment: If I want to write variables into a file and output their values, how would I do that using this method?

Comment: @JWONTSEEIT I'm not sure I understand the question

Comment: I tried doing as you suggested but my code still returns the same error message

Comment: ah, `json.dump` in a file opened for appending won't include newlines. I'll edit my answer

Comment: StringIO isn't actually necessary right? Json.dumps converts my dictionary into a string

Comment: Right, `StringIO` was just a stand in for reading a file, purely for example purposes